# Desapilar filas de un dataframe aumentando el número de columnas

Tags: r

En primer lugar comentar que estoy empezando a programar y, por tanto, mis conocimientos aún son escasos.

Bien, resulta que he descargado una serie de datos de distintos años sucesivos hasta 2021 de una serie de variable medidas. Como resultado, se descarga un archivo .csv, y apila los resultados para las distintas variables una debajo de otra, a partir de unas columnas comunes.
A ese archivo .csv le he eliminado las columnas que no son necesarias y he convertido la solución en un dataframe.

Posteriormente he obtenido una nueva columna que es la diferencia de el año de la fila siguiente menos el de a propia fila, dando así un resultado de 1 en años sucesivos, y un resultado negativo cuando hay un salto de años y se trata por tanto de otra variable.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(diferencia = df$Año - lag(df$Año, 1))

df$diferencia[1] <- df$diferencia[2]

También he añadido una columna de identificación

df <- cbind(ID = 1:nrow(df),df)

     ID  Año   Área        Producto       Elemento      Valor    Unidad diferencia
1     1 1990 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada       0.00        ha          1
2     2 1991 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada   11828.00        ha          1
3     3 1992 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada   12502.00        ha          1
```

La duda viene aquí. El objetivo no deja de ser otro que pasar del df de 8 columnas y 400 filas a, o bien tantos dataframes distintos como variables haya, o como tienen la columna común del año, poner una al lado de la otra.
Había pensado en hacer un bucle que me de el valor del ID de las filas con valores negativos de la columna diferencia y a partir de ahí dividir el dataframe en varios, pero no sé si esta solución es factible. Acepto cualquier propuesta.

Gracias de antemano

Edit: Añado ejemplos de las variables:

```
unique(df$Área)
 "España"
unique(df$Producto)
 "Cereales n.c.p."              "Ganado vacuno"               
 "Leche cruda de ganado bovino" "Maíz"                        
unique(df$Elemento)
 "Área cosechada" "Rendimiento"    "Producción"     "Existencias"
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Estás pidiendo una opinión, algo que no entra dentro del formato del sitio, te puedo dar la mía como comentario y decirte que no veo nada mal en la estructura de tus datos, de hecho se adapta bien al principio de "tidy data", pero desconozco que es lo que quieres hacer, si buscas hacer gráficas con `ggplot` esta es la estructura perfecta ¿Para que quieres dataframes separados? ¿para que los años todos juntos?

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio por tu respuesta. Quizá sea por desconocimiento de este lenguaje o porque no me esté expresando del todo bien. Tengo 10 variables anuales, en total 40 mediciones por variable. El problema es que al descargarlo, todas se han apilado y se ha puesto una a continuación de la otra, resultando una tabla de 8 columnas y 400 filas. Sin embargo, yo lo que quiero es tener 40 filas (porque hay 40 mediciones a cada variable), las columnas año y área comunes, y luego las columnas producto, elemento, valor y unidad para cada variable, para así poder hacer estadísticas por columnas.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo de las variables?, por ejemplo `unique(df$Area)` , `unique(df$Producto)` y `unique(df$Elemento)`

Comment: Por supuesto, ya edité la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Imaginando un ejemplo como el siguiente:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID, Año, Área, Producto, Elemento, Valor, Unidad
1, 1990, España, Cereales n.c.p., Área cosechada,       0.00,        ha
2, 1991, España, Cereales n.c.p., Área cosechada,   11828.00,        ha
3, 1992, España, Cereales n.c.p., Área cosechada,   12502.00,        ha
4, 1990, España, Ganado vacuno, Producción, 15000, un", header=TRUE, sep= ",", strip.white=TRUE)

df

  ID  Año   Área        Producto       Elemento Valor Unidad
1  1 1990 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada     0     ha
2  2 1991 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada 11828     ha
3  3 1992 España Cereales n.c.p. Área cosechada 12502     ha
4  4 1990 España   Ganado vacuno     Producción 15000     un
```

Entiendo que lo que podrías hacer es emplear `pivot_wider()` del paquete `tidyr`, estableciendo a `Producto` como columna a expandir hacía lo ancho:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c("Producto"),
              values_from=c("Valor"))

# A tibble: 4 x 7
     ID   Año Área   Elemento       Unidad `Cereales n.c.p.` `Ganado vacuno`
  <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>          <chr>              <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1  1990 España Área cosechada ha                     0              NA
2     2  1991 España Área cosechada ha                 11828              NA
3     3  1992 España Área cosechada ha                 12502              NA
4     4  1990 España Producción     un                    NA           15000
```

O incluso solo por `Año`:

```
df %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c("Producto", "Elemento"),
              names_sep ="/",

# A tibble: 3 x 6
    Año Área   `Valor/Cereales n.c.p./Área cosechada` `Valor/Ganado vacuno/Producción` `Unidad/Cereales n.c.p./Área cosechada` Unidad/Ganado ~1
  <int> <chr>                                   <dbl>                            <dbl> <chr>                                   <chr>           
1  1990 España                                      0                            15000 ha                                      un              
2  1991 España                                  11828                               NA ha                                      NA              
3  1992 España                                  12502                               NA ha                                      NA              
# ... with abbreviated variable name 1: `Unidad/Ganado vacuno/Producción`
```